# Image not Retaining on secondViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have 3 `ViewControllers`, 1st one loads `UIImagePickerController` 2nd displays image picked from 1st `ViewControllers` `UIImagePickerController` in an `UIImageView`, and has a button which Loads `thirdViewController`, this `ViewController` has images displayed in `UIImageView` which i want to load on the `secondViewController` also inside the `UIImageView` but the images i want to be able to move and stretch, then save to a bitmap and pass to an email using `MFMailComposeViewController` which i have already written a template for (the emailing works)

the problems I'm having are -

- when i press the `button` to load the `thirdViewController` and come back to `secondViewController` the image selected in the `firstViewController's` `UIImagePickerController` has disappeared (not being retained) (solved)
- I'm very lost when it comes to using the images from the `thirdViewController` in the `secondViewController` in the way that I'm not sure how to turn them into buttons that load the images onto the `UIImageView` in the `secondViewController`
- I don't know the code to use to post the saved bitmap inside the image once the images have all been merged into said bitmap

Thank you for answers in advance here is some code:

**firstViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import "secondViewController.h"
@interface spViewController : UIViewController


<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property BOOL newMedia;


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) spViewController *secondViewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *image;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *myImage;

- (IBAction)useCamera:(id)sender;


- (IBAction)useCameraRoll:(id)sender;


@end
```

**firstViewController.m**

```
#import "spViewController.h"
#import "secondViewController.h"

@interface spViewController ()

@end

@implementation spViewController
@synthesize myImage;

- (IBAction)backtohome:(UIStoryboardSegue *)unwindSegue
{
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)useCamera:(id)sender
{
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType =
        UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                           animated:YES completion:nil];
        _newMedia = NO;
    }
}

- (IBAction)useCameraRoll:(id)sender
{

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum])
    {
        UIImagePickerController *imagePicker =
        [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString *) kUTTypeImage];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES; //change NO to YES
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker
                           animated:YES completion:nil];
        _newMedia = NO;
    }
}



//image picker delegate
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    UIImage *chosenImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    //it returns the edited image

    NSString *mediaType = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
    self.myImage = chosenImage;


    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage])
    {

        UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

        _imageView.image = image;
        if (_newMedia)
        {

        }
        else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
        {

        }
    }

    [self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:picker afterDelay:0.5];



}


-(void)image:(UIImage *)image finishedSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
    {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle: @"Save failed"
                                  message: @"Failed to save image"
                                  delegate: nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
    }
    //cancel delegate

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)myMethod:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Perform segue");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Picture Unwind Segue" sender:self];
    }]; 
}


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
        if ([[segue identifier]isEqualToString:@"Picture Unwind Segue"])
        {
            secondViewController *destinationViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
            destinationViewController.myImage = self.myImage; //just set the image of secondViewController
       }
}

    @end
```

**secondViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
#import "spViewController.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "selectselfViewController.h"

@interface secondViewController : UIViewController

<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
UINavigationControllerDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImage *myImage;
@property (strong) UIImageView *Viewofimage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

- (IBAction)openShelfPage:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)emailSupport:(id)sender;


@end
```

**secondViewController.m**

```
#import "secondViewController.h"
#import "spViewController.h"

@interface secondViewController ()

@end

@implementation secondViewController
@synthesize myImage;



- (IBAction)emailSupport:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"sender %@",[sender description]);


    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"info@bespokenature.co.uk",nil]];
    [mailComposer setSubject:@"Request for quote"];
    NSString *supportText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please state the dimentions you would like, the number of shelfs and the colour"];
    supportText = [supportText stringByAppendingString: @"add any further details here"];
    [mailComposer setMessageBody:supportText isHTML:NO];
    [self presentViewController:mailComposer animated:YES completion:nil];


}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}



- (IBAction)openShelfPage:(id)sender
{}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _imageView.image = self.myImage;
    _imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;



}

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

}


@end
```

**thirdViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface selectselfViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)backtoSVC:(id)sender;

@end
```

**thirdViewController.m**

```
#import "selectselfViewController.h"

@interface selectselfViewController ()

@end

@implementation selectselfViewController

- (IBAction)backtoSVC:(id)sender{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Once again Thank you

EDIT: i added all the code from my app so theres more information.

EDIT 2: I have added some informations below to explain the app and the problems a little better

**Functions of the app**

I was asked to make this app for a carpentry company that specialises in "floating shelves" they wanted an where the user can take a photo of the wall then pick from a  catalog of shelfs place the shelfs on the wall (numerous amounts of shelfs) stretch and fit to size then press a button and save the whole image (inc. Shelfs) and send it in an email to the owner of the company so he can send back a quote for them.

**Thus Far**

- I have set up the buttons to open `UIImagePickerController`
- I have Made it so the app displays the picture taken from the `UIImagePickerController`in my `secondViewController`
- I have set up the button that takes you to the `thirdViewController`
- I have placed the shelves to be selected by the user in the `thirdViewController` as `UIImageViews`

**Things I have not done**

- Made the images of the shelves in the `thirdViewController` selectable to be placed on the `UIImageView` where the picture of the wall is being displayed
- Save the image ready to be imported into the email (`MFMailComposeViewController`)

Comment: Starting with problem #1….  When you say "come back to secondViewController", how is that being done?  Try logging the value of `self` inside the secondViewController's `viewDidAppear:` method and see if it's actually the same controller object.

Comment: at the moment its just being done through a button, "cancel" button to be exact so from the second VC a button opens the thirdVC but if the person wants to cancel and change the image they press cancel to go back to the secondVC, soon i want the images on the thirdVC to go back to the secondVC and also be displayed there... this is why i posted all of the problems together cause they are all linked :) thank you for your reply

Comment: OK, but what happens when the Cancel is tapped?  Does it simply dismiss thirdVC or is there other processing?

Comment: ummm, i just ctrl dragged the button back to the secondViewController.

Comment: Try the suggestion above of printing `self`.  I suspect there are two different secondVC objects involved: one that you give the image to and another one created by the Cancel.

Comment: that problem is fixed now thank you, i put this inside my button methods `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];` 1 down 2 to go, thank you so much for your help! any idea about my other 2 problems?

Comment: Do you have a github repo that has the project I could look at?

Comment: i have uploaded it to dropbox as i don't have github i don't have a github but i have put it into drop box here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/9wu3khgb4baqswv/Shelf%20Planner.zip

Comment: I have taken a look at your project. Although you could very well use simple view controllers without any containers, you're giving yourself way too much overhead. There are no benefits to do this in your app. Stick with a UINavigationController and go from there. Take a look at the example I made for you on GitHub.

Comment: And forget about unwind segues for now. Wait until you have a solid understanding of navigating between view controllers before you start exploring them.

Comment: How do i get the example you made? Thank you

Comment: You can download it from here: https://github.com/bensarz/so-23826880

Comment: I looked at the example, thank you, i don't see the connection with calling the images to use when selected to use on the `SVC` UIImageView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54545/discussion-between-bensarz-and-c-wetherell).

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on problem #2
We'll probably need more information on problem #3, it's not clear to me what you mean by 'post', perhaps it should be its own question.

#### Problem #2

I'm assuming you are using a UINavigationController. You have to understand that a navigation controller has a stack of view controllers. When you first launch the application and you get to your `FirstViewController` the stack looks like this:
|---`FirstViewController`---|

When you go to your second view controller, the first view controller is still in memory but is not on the screen. The stack looks like this:
|---`FirstViewController`---|---`SecondViewController`---|

Again when you go to your third view controller, the first and second view controller are still in memory but are not on the screen. The stack looks like this:
|---`FirstViewController`---|---`SecondViewController`---|---`ThirdViewController`---|

What you're effectively doing by control-dragging from your third view controller to your second view controller is this (it is possible to do this but your questions hint me to the fact that you don't know about Unwind Segues, so I'm assuming you're just using a normal segue):
|---`FirstViewController`---|---`SecondViewController`---|---`ThirdViewController`---|---**`SecondViewController`**---|

In fact, what you want to do is 'remove' the third view controller from memory but tell your second view controller that something happened in the third view controller. You can achieve this in multiple ways... My personal preference is using blocks. You can use a ThirdViewController delegate if you want to but that's too much overhead in my opinion. You can add a block as a property on the third view controller and implement the block in the `prepareForSegue:sender:` method of the second view controller. Something like this in the third view controller...

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^onImageSelected)(UIImage *image);
```

...and the corresponding code in the second view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    ThirdViewController *thirdViewController = (ThirdViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    [thirdViewController setOnImageSelected:^(UIImage *image) {
        // Do something here
        // This is the call back
    }];
}
```

Make sure to call the block (and check if it is nil before calling it) when an image is selected in the thirdViewController or when the user presses back. Then you'd put the call in the `dealloc` method:

```
// Image was selected
if (self.onImageSelected)
    self.onImageSelected(selectedImage);
```

Comment: I'm not using a `UINavigationController` (should i be? i have not used them before but ill look for a tutorial if its mandatory to use), by post I mean once the user has selected how many images they want to put on top of the image they selected from the `UIImagePickerController` it merges all of the images and then puts that one image in the email as an attachment ready to send.
I hope this makes sense.

Comment: when you say `//do something here //this is the call back` what do you mean?

Comment: Are you using storyboards?

Comment: In the code your posted, where do you go from second view controller to third view controller?

Comment: yes, i am using storyboards, and i goto the thirdviewcontroller using the openShelfPage `IBAction`

Comment: I made a quick example for you using block: https://github.com/bensarz/so-23826880